# SQL divide results into 2 columns

Tags: sql

I have a question about retrieving data using SQL

i want to get

```
count(comments_id) where comment_year = 2012 and 
count(comments_id) where comment_year = 2013
```

in one query to get the output like this:

```
year12_comments  |  year13_comments
7                |  8
```

I hope its clear.

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN comment_year = 2012 THEN 1 END) year12_comments,
COUNT(CASE WHEN comment_year = 2013 THEN 1 END) year13_comments,
```

If you are using `MS SQL Server 2005` or above, you can use `PIVOT`

Comment: @techdo `COUNT` of course, `SUM` is not applicable, when no records(all values is `NULL`) its returns `NULL` but `COUNT` `0` instead.

Comment: You can use either one (COUNT or SUM) to get the result.

Comment: @bluefeet if there is no record in the group you will get `NULL` but by `COUNT` you will get `0` instead.

Comment: That is correct. All I am saying is that you can use either the `count` or the `sum` to get the result.

Comment: @bluefeet `SELECT SUM(val), COUNT(val) FROM (VALUES(CAST(NULL as INT))) T(val)` Explain result of this query, please.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan You are not understanding what I am saying, in terms of pivoting the data you can use either `COUNT` or `SUM` to get the result! See this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db582/3

Comment: @HamletHakobyan for that case you would add `else 0` -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8efc8/2

Comment: @bluefeet OK :) But with `COUNT` is simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Like this

```
...
SUM(CASE WHEN comment_year = 2012 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year12_comments,
SUM(CASE WHEN comment_year = 2013 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year13_comments,
...
```

---

**Update:**

If you want to get the percentage between them, you can enclose them in a subquery like this:

```
SELECT 
   (year12_comments / year13_comments) * 100
FROM
(
  SELECT
     ...
     SUM(CASE WHEN comment_year = 2012 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year12_comments,
     SUM(CASE WHEN comment_year = 2013 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year13_comments,
     ...

 ) sub
```

---

### Update2

If you want to make the `year12_comments, year13_comments` as well as the percentage new column, just include them in the `SELECT` statement like this:

```
SELECT 
  year12_comments, 
  year13_comments,
  (year12_comments / year13_comments) * 100 AS ThePercenatge 
FROM
(
  SELECT
     ...
     SUM(CASE WHEN comment_year = 2012 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year12_comments,
     SUM(CASE WHEN comment_year = 2013 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year13_comments,
     ...

) sub
```

Comment: ok, what if i would like to get the percentage between them too ?

Comment: thanks :) but both of year12_comments,year13_comments don't appear in the result how can i show year12_comments,year13_comments and percentage ?

Comment: @SayedFathy Just put them in the select clause and don't forget to give the new percentage column an alias. See my edit. And if any thing else goes wrong don't hesitate to ask again. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can use the PIVOT function @HamletHakobyan suggested, IMHO this is a bad decision. Unless (another) end of the World happens in 2013, you'll have to do this for 2014 too. I'd rather go with a simple group by for the user and the year too:

```
SELECT user_id, comment_year, count(1)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY user_id, comment_year
```

Sure, you'll have to code a bit in your application, but from a clarity aspect, this seems to be the way to go...

(BTW I think this will be quicker than the `CASE WHEN` structure too...)